# Trying to create a string in awk, complains about division with zero

Tags: bash, unix, awk, terminal

I am trying to create a script to automagically create symlinks to all my folders under a specific folder, this should ot be to hard to do but for some reason my variables are passed around really odd inside this oneline script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ----------------------------------
# --------- TotalKrill -------------
# ----------------------------------
# Script to create symlinks to my clouded folder in my home directory by listing all  folders/files in the cloudfolder and then creating symlinks in destfolder
# 
myname=`whoami`
searchfolderdir=/home/$myname/
searchfoldername=ownCloud
destfolder=~/
Target=$searchfolderdir$searchfoldername/

ls -1 $searchfolderdir$searchfoldername | awk {'print ln -fs $Target$0 $destfolder/$0'} #|sh
```

But I get an output : awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Can anyone please point me on a better approach or tell me how to fix this script?
the "| sh" is commented out so i can get a correct line before running.

On a ubuntu 12.10 x64 box trying to get it working.

Comment: a couple of comments/questions: 1) could there be spaces or other special chars in your dir/filenames? 2) `ls -1` returns files too do you only want to create those **dir**s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is *(syntactically at least)*:

```
awk -v t="$Target" -v d="$desfolder" '{print "ln -fs",t$0,d"/",$0}'
```

Notes:

- If you don't want the division operator but the literal char `/` you need to inclose it in double quotes.
- Strings need enclosing in double quotes in `awk` like the string `ln -fs`
- You need to pass shell variables to awk using the `-v` option.
- You should always quote your variables.
- The curly braces that in-close the block need to be inside the single quotes.

---

Adding a couple of other fixes like using `find` to return only directories:

```
#!/bin/bash

myname=$(whoami)
dir="/home/$myname/"
folder="myCloud"
destination="~/"
target="${dir}${folder}"

find "${target}" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | 
awk -v t="$target" -v d="$destination" '{print "ln -fs",t$0"/",d}'
```

Comment: ls -1 $searchfolderdir$searchfoldername | awk -v t="$Target" -v d="$searchfolderdir"  '{print "ln -fs "t$0,d$0}' | sh